# how can i fix 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

help me fix this problem please...

this is my code:

```
    private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) > 17) //error here in this line
        {
            groupBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            groupBox1.Enabled = true;
        }


        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox9.Text, "[^0-9]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
            textBox9.Text = "";
        }


    }
```

Comment: I guess the text-content is not parsable as int?! Use TryParse

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx), that exception is thrown when `value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).`. Therefore, provide a value that is a valid integer.

Comment: Maybe whitespaces or something - Trim()

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Comment: @Maipoi Licalie: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

rather than use `Convert.ToInt32(` make use of [`int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), because there is problem if you pass value which is not integer.

```
     int number = 0;
     bool result = Int32.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out number);
     if (result)
     {
        if (number > 17) 
          {
              groupBox1.Enabled = false;
         }
        else
         {
            groupBox1.Enabled = true;
         }       
     }
```

in C# 7.0 you can do this , you dont need to declare variable outside

```
     if (Int32.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out int number))
     {
        if (number > 17) 
          {
              groupBox1.Enabled = false;
         }
        else
         {
            groupBox1.Enabled = true;
         }       
     }
```

Comment: you don't even need the variable 'result'

Comment: @TimvanPeterson-- yeah but for better understanding i kept there ..we can direcly put statement inside if , and yes in new version C# 7.0(i guess) you can define variable inside too

Comment: @MaipoiLicalie - welcome, please do accept upvote if worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Put `TryParse`, not `Parse` or `Convert`:

```
  int value = 0;

  groupBox1.Enabled = int.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out value) && value <= 17;
```

So we `Enable` the `groupBox1` if and only if

1. `textBox9.Text` contains valid integer `value`
2. The `value` is less or equal to `17`

Please, be *nice* and do not *reject* white spaces (like, say, trailing spaces: `"123 "`) with `...Regex.IsMatch(textBox9.Text, "[^0-9]")...`. Once again, try parsing:

```
if (!int.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out value)) {
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
}
```